# Include jar file in source code and during compile

Tags: jar, classpath, javac, java

I have made my custom jar file and compiled it using

```
path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin;%path%
javac *.java
jar cvf QLibrary.jar *.class
```

Then I took that jar file and put it in the same directory where my `Main.java` is located

`Main.java` is going to use classes that are in the jar

So I have decided to put `import QLibrary.*;` inside `Main.java`

And I compile using

```
path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin;%path%
javac -cp ".;*.jar" *java
```

But apparently it does not recognize the library or the classes in it. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either list the names of all your jar files:

```
javac -cp ".;QLibrary.jar" *java
```

or you could use wildcards in this way:

```
javac -cp ".;*" *java
```

Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character `*`, which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension `.jar` or `.JAR`. For example, the class path entry `foo/*` specifies all JAR files in the directory named foo. A classpath entry consisting simply of `*` expands to a list of all the jar files in the current directory.
... For example, if the directory `foo` contains `a.jar`, `b.jar`, and `c.jar`, then the class path `foo/*` is expanded into `foo/a.jar;foo/b.jar;foo/c.jar`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: Should that be `./*` instead of `lib/*`?

Comment: Yeah! if the jar files are located in the current directory, specifying `./*` would be expanded, e.g., to `./a.jar;./b.jar;...`  and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. Can you adjust your answer please? It can be confusing how `".;QLibrary.jar"` can be replaced by `".;lib/*"`.

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in [javac -cp option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html), if you are using `Windows`, try `java -cp .;QLibrary.jar mysource`